# unable to read from MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I want to display the total number of P_IN based on dateTimePicker at my window form in Visual Studio 2010, but its getting error where the program cannot read data from the MySQL.Below is my code.

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DATE, P_IN FROM Database.CounterDb WHERE DATE = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'", con);
                      MySqlDataAdapter sdaa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                      DataSet dataa = new DataSet();
                      sdaa.Fill(dataa, "Database.CounterDb");
                      reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      int sum = 0;
                       while (reader.Read())
                        {

                             sum = reader.GetInt32(1) + sum;

                          }
                          LCounter.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: "Database.CounterDb" is it your table name?

Comment: **WARNING**: Don't forget to use **prepared statements** and avoid inserting arbitrary user data in your queries. [It's not hard to do properly](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) and avoids a whole lot of [ugly side-effects](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: yes,,that my table name

Answer (score 0):

this code is really dangerous,
you must not add directly the user input to a query 
do not use

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DATE, P_IN FROM Database.CounterDb WHERE DATE = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'", con);
```

the user input could broke the query, the date text format could not be in the right format

use this (REPLACE DATE FORMAT WITH YOURS):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = con;
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATE, P_IN FROM Database.CounterDb WHERE DATE = @dt";
   cmd.Prepare();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
```

ELSE if you need to search in a range for example 2016-02-20 00:00:00  - 2016-02-20 23:59:59, you have to query for all entry in this date:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
DateTime dt1 = dt.AddDays(1);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATE, P_IN FROM Database.CounterDb WHERE DATE > @dt and DATE <@dt1";
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", dt1);
```

Comment: The error is still the same. still cannot display the total number of P_IN

Comment: I have checked using message box,the program cannot read this part of the program,,   sdaa.Fill(data, "Database.CounterDb");
                            
                            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            
                            int sum = 0;
                          
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                sum = reader.GetInt32(1) + sum;
                            }
                            LCounter.Text = sum.ToString();

Comment: the loop reader.Read() found data? what is the final value of sum?

Comment: if I remove the DATE and WHERE DATE = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text +  statement, the sum will display sum of P_IN in the database, but right now I want to display sum of P_IN based on DATE.

Comment: Good!!! now.. your database filed is a date or a date time? if you have a date time you need to query in a range, for today DATE>'2016-05-01' and DATE<'2016-05-02'

Comment: but I want for today value only; my data filed is a date

Comment: sorry,,i want the value based on dateTimePicker,,